# MSVS 2010 C: memory detection working as expected

Tags: c, visual-studio, memory-leaks

I am working on a C project in MSVS 2010 (meaning I am using malloc, calloc, and free, not the C++ new and delete operators).  I need to find a memory leak(s?), so I've followed the steps on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx to get the program to dump the memory state at the end of the run.

I include the libraries like so:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

I also specify that every exit should display the debug info like so:

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
```

But my debug output looks like this:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{80181} normal block at 0x016B1D38, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <  7   7 8 7 > 0C D5 37 00 14 A9 37 00 38 99 37 00 
{80168} normal block at 0x016ACC20, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <  7 H 7 X 7 \ 7 > A8 FB 37 00 48 E9 37 00 58 C2 37 00 5C AC 37 00 
...
```

According to the article, I should be getting file name and line number output indicating where the leaked memory is allocated.  Why is this not happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does VS have a switch for debug build vs release build? If so, is this a debug build or a release build?

Comment: Make sure nothing else is including those files first without the #define beforehand...

Comment: To reinforce what Jon Cage said, watch out for precompiled headers.  You might need to do a rebuild all or to define _CRT_MAP_ALLOC with a compiler option rather than in the file.  That will make sure it's defined in every compilation unit.

Comment: It cannot show you `__FILE__` info for code that was unloaded.  DLLs typically.  Or code that was compiled without #including crtdbg.h.  The block numbers are too high to give crtBreakAlloc good odds, but you could try.

Comment: Adrian, post your comment as the answer!  Ensuring all my files had the defines and includes fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adrian McCarthy commented that I should ensure that the definition _CRT_MAP_ALLOC existed in every compilation unit.  While I could not figure out how to define that as a compiler option, I did create a sparse header file that I ensured every compiled file included.  This made the debugging functionality work as expected.